# Double integral of $\exp\left(\frac{x-y}{x+y}\right)$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

How can i take the double integral of $\exp\left(\frac{x-y}{x+y}\right)$ on the domain
$S:=\{x^2+y^2=1, x^2+y^2=9,x>0,y>0\}$

if i transform it to polar coordinates, i have the integral

$\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}e^{\frac{cos\theta-sin\theta}{cos\theta+sin\theta}}d\theta$

if we apply the change of variable $u=x-y,v=x+y$, domain will be
$R=\{u^2+v^2=2, u^2+v^2=18,u,v>0\}$ and integral will be\

$\int\int\limits_{R}e^{\frac{u}{v}}\frac{1}{2}dudv$

Comment: Can you solve the problem with your latest edit?

Comment: i tried to solve with change of variables. Then i transformed it to polar coordinates, But i had  the $\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{cotx} d\theta$. it does not converge.